# VBA message box not working for in the on error goto

Tags: excel, vba

Below is a function that I've written in VBA.

```
Option Explicit

Function MyMatrix(mtx As Range, vec As Range) As Variant
    On Error GoTo Exception

    Dim M
    M = Application.MInverse(mtx)

    MyMatrix = Application.MMult(M, vec)

    Exit Function
Exception:
    MsgBox prompt:="Test", Buttons:=[vbOKCancel,vbCritical], Title:="Two"
End Function
```

However, when I try to use it, the msgbox is not showing up for an error. 
Below, is a matrix that has a determinate zero, which you can't multiple with another vector. I believe my code is recognizing that the determinate is zero because I get the error in the box on the spreadsheet, but my message box dosen't pop up. What would cause this error?

I've tried to read through some other examples, but they didn't help. And I don't want to use "On Error Resume Next" instead.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force UDF in VBA to display a MsgBox when the user enters more than expected arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749046/force-udf-in-vba-to-display-a-msgbox-when-the-user-enters-more-than-expected-arg)

Comment: Probably none of your functions throws a VBA exception. Note that `Application.MMult` will return an error code as result like `Error 2015` but it will return it to your function (and show up as result in your cell) and not throw an Exception. • Anyway I think it's no good idea to use a message box in a UDF. This could easily throw a box for each formula you have on the sheet -> happy clicking.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of calling worksheet functions from VBA:

1) Application.MInverse 
2) Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse

When an error occurs 1) returns a variant containing an error, but 2) raises an error.
So you either need to use 1) with `If Iserror(M) Then` or 2) with your existing code.

Note using 2) is faster than 1)

See also my blog post on UDFs https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/06/06/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-2/

Comment: In addition to this answer: Avoid using `MsgBox` in a UDF. Instead return an error value eg with [CVErr Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/cverr-function) like `MyMatrix = CVErr(xlErrValue)`